# getting all subattachment from facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the following facebook request:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/_fb_page_id_/feed?access_token=_access_token_&fields=description,attachments,message&limit=100

to get the feed of facebook api but it only returns max 12 subattachments while the posts include more 12 attached image.

- the images are not album so I can't use album method.

any idea how to get all the images attached to the posts with the description for it ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a limit for the attachments?

Comment: @CBroe i added the limit at the end of the request like the above url, how to specify limit for the attachments only ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: Thanks alot ! 
it worked for the subattachments not the attachment.
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/_page_id/feed?access_token=_access_token_&fields=description,attachments{subattachments.limit(100)},message&limit=100

thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According @CBroe's hint, the solution was to modify the URL like below:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/YOUR_PAGE_ID_HERE/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE&fields=description,attachments{subattachments.limit(100)},message&limit=100`